# ROS Answers SE migration: Hector_gps

Tags: gazebo, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was trying to simulate a gps using the hector_gazebo_gps plugin, but something is not right.
I tested it by moving the robot 34 meters and used

http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/cgi-bin/NDSFutility.cgi?form=0&from=XY&to=LatLon

To figure the right values of lat and long and verify them in google earth.

But in the navsafix message published by the plugin I barely moved.

I cannot figure what's wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37400/hector_gps/) by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-06-27**:
Hello, can you be more specific about how you tested, and also about the published message you observed?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-07-03**:
Congratulations!! Can you post what you did as an answer to your question? And if the changes require a patch for a package could you share that as well?

**Comment by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on 2012-07-09**:
I would post it but I don't know if the hector gps simulator as a problem or why was just using it wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've solved the problem by making some modifications to the code using the geodesy package. Now the gps simulator works fine. I failed to discovered what I was doing wrong in the hector gps package

---

Originally posted by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) with karma: 92 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0